# Why does this unit test with promise wrapped $resource fail (but works fine in the running app)?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

(I expect the root of my issue is that I've not written my unit test correctly but i'm not sure how to correct it.)

Please see the two linked Plunkers for full code and the explanation below for details:

[Plunker #1](http://plnkr.co/edit/6dtHPscQhHhoubws8p8a) - Working fine in the UI
Run this plunker to see it working fine in the running app.  Note that as you type in the `<input>`, the browser console shows REST calls executing, each with the updated value of the `<input>` appended as a querystring parameter.  **This is working as expected in the UI.**

[Plunker #2](http://plnkr.co/edit/dHWvVKoEaeR0wWL8f2cK) - Failing in the unit test
Run this plunker to see the failing unit test.  **And I can't figure out why this test fails.**

---

I've tried to make the example plunkers as simple as possible.  The plunkers show all the code, but I'll paste some of the relevant code below.

The use case is:
 1. when the controller loads, initial data is loaded via a $resource that is wrapped by a promise ($q). (`MultiTagLoader`)
 2. `ng-change` event on an `<input>` triggers function in same controller (`$scope.searchChange`) which executes new query using value of `<input>`

Here's the unit test.  The second test always fails because the URL isn't matching the `expectGET` URL.

```
it('should load an initial list of Tags', function () {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('tags.json?query=DEFAULT_SEARCH_TERM').
    respond([{"id": 1, "name": "Hibernate"}, {"id": 12, "name": "JAX-RS"}]);

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(scope.tags).toEqualData([{"id": 1, "name": "Hibernate"}, {"id": 12, "name": "JAX-RS"}]);
});

it('should invoke search function on scope.searchChange()', function () {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('tags.json?query=foo').
    respond([{"id": 1, "name": "Hibernate"}, {"id": 12, "name": "JAX-RS"}]);

    scope.searchChange('foo');
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(scope.tags).toEqualData([{"id": 1, "name": "Hibernate"}, {"id": 12, "name": "JAX-RS"}]);
});
```

Error:

```
Controller test: ListCtrl should invoke search function on scope.searchChange().
Error: Unexpected request: GET tags.json?query=DEFAULT_SEARCH_TERM 
Expected GET tags.json?query=foo
```

The controller code (as seen in the plunkers) is calling this factory:

```
myServices.factory('MultiTagLoader', ['TagRestSvc', '$q',
function(TagRestSvc, $q) {
    return {
        query: function(params) {
            var delay = $q.defer();
            TagRestSvc.query(params, function(tags) {
                delay.resolve(tags);
            }, function() {
                delay.reject('Unable to fetch Tags');
            });
            return delay.promise;
         }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new instance of your controller will be created before each spec. This means that the default request will be made not only in your first spec but in your second as well.

While you can solve this by adding the request expectation from the first spec to your second one, this it not really what you want. Instead you want to set up a backend defintion for the entire suite.

For example:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('ListCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });

    $httpBackend.whenGET('tags.json?query=DEFAULT_SEARCH_TERM').respond([{"id": 1, "name": "Hibernate"}, {"id": 12, "name": "JAX-RS"}]);
}));
```

The difference between a `request expectation` and a `backend defintion` is explained in the $httpBackend [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend):

> Request expectations provide a way to make assertions about requests
>   made by the application and to define responses for those requests.
>   The test will fail if the expected requests are not made or they are
>   made in the wrong order.
>
> Backend definitions allow you to define a fake backend for your
>   application which doesn't assert if a particular request was made or
>   not, it just returns a trained response if a request is made. The test
>   will pass whether or not the request gets made during testing.

With the new backend defintion added your first spec will still fail if the default request is not made, since it contains an expectation for it. Your second spec however will only fail if the searchChange-request is not made. It will still make the default request and get the response data from the backend definition, but it will not fail if the request is not made. You can observe this be removing the default request from the controller.

**Demo of the specs passing:** http://plnkr.co/edit/yCOVReYvYEHQXeSKE0ja?p=preview